# Need a richtext UIControl for cocoa touch

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, rich-text-editor

Can i find some rich text editor control for xcode? Just the basic functionality textformatting b,i option, link, image embed. Ordedered/unordered lists not needed, but good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iPad only:
https://github.com/omnigroup/OmniGroup/tree/master/Frameworks/OmniUI/iPad/Examples/TextEditor/Classes